# Edward's Venn diagram for Three sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

please can anyone explain? what is meant for three hemispheres in Edward's Venn diagram for 3 sets? and where do we represent intersecting regions in Edward's Venn diagram for 3 sets?[Edward's Venn diagram for 3 sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p3HW.png)

Answer (score 2):

The right side is the first set, the bottom side is the second set, and the circle is the third set. So if you wanted to represent something in the first and third sets but not the second, that would be in the top right sector of the circle; if you wanted to represent something in the first and second but not the third, that would be the bottom right corner of the rectangles.

Comment: thank you soooo much sir..I am very thank full to you

Comment: @T.Noor: If an answer helps you, you can consider clicking the arrow on the left to vote it up. You can also click the checkmark to mark it as an "accepted answer", which will give you 2 rep points as a bonus.